# Linear regression question on Idempotent matrix and leverage points

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, matrix, leverage, inequality

I am considering a linear regression model $Y_i = X_i^T \beta + \epsilon_i, i = 1,2,\dots,n$. where $X_i \in \mathbb{R}^p$. $\epsilon_i$'s are independent copies of random error $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^1$ with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$.
We have the  hat matrix given by 
$$ H = X^T (X^TX)^{-1} X$$
I am trying to show $h_{ij}^2 \leq h_{ii} h_{kk}$.
I know that $$h_{ij} = X_i^T (X^T X)^{-1} X_j$$ and that $H^2 = H$ because it is idempotent. This gives me $\sum_{k=1}^n h_{ik}^2 = h_{ii}$ but I don't know how to prove $h_{ij}^2 \leq h_{ii} h_{jj}$.

Comment: H is the covariance matrix of the parameters. That is the covariance divided by (sqrt) variance of elements is the correlation that is always less than one.

Comment: H is the covariance matrix of fitted values..$ Cov(\hat{Y}) = H\sigma^2$. Now your argument works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is [the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). Let $H=X (X^T X)^{-1} X^T$ where $X$ is the design matrix in the linear model $Y_i = X_i^T \beta + \epsilon_i$, $X_i$ is the $i$th row of the design matrix. Since $(X^TX)^{-1}$ is positive definite, we can define an inner product by 
$$
    h_{ij} =\langle X_i, X_j \rangle = X_i^T (X^TX)^{-1} X_j
$$
and by the Cauchy-Schwarts inequality
$$
   h_{ij} = |h_{ij}| = |\langle X_i,X_j\rangle |\le \sqrt{\langle X_i,X_i\rangle \langle X_j, X_j \rangle} =\sqrt{h_{ii} h_{jj}}
$$

Comment: should the first equality in the last display not be $\leq$?