# Query regarding hat matrix

Tags: regression, self-study, linear-model

Let us consider a linear regression model $\underline{Y} = X \underline{\beta} + \underline{\epsilon}$, where X is an $n \times p$ matrix, rank($X$) = $p$, $E(\underline{\epsilon}) = \underline{0}$, $D(\underline{\epsilon}) = \sigma^2 I$.

(Here, $E(.)$ stands for expectation, $D(.)$ denotes the variance covariance matrix and $I$ is the $n$-th order identity matrix.)

Let the $n \times n$ hat matrix $H$ be defined as $H = \big( \big( h_{ij} \big) \big) = X (X^{'}X)^{-1}X^{'}$.

If $h_{ii} = 0$ or $1$ for some $i$, then how can I show $h_{ij} = 0$ for all $j \neq i$?

Comment: I have tagged this as self-study. It looks like homework, or for your own conceptual enrichment. Correct answers are hints, not solutions. Can you explain what you have tried or what you do? Do you, for instance, know that $H$ is idempotent and what the properties of such matrices are?

Comment: Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229461/linear-regression-question-on-idempotent-matrix-and-leverage-points/350980#350980

Comment: Although the duplicate does not ask this specific question, its result easily implies the result.  If you want to solve the problem directly in the most elementary way, write out the formula for the diagonal terms in $H^2 = H$ and use the symmetry of $H$ to draw the conclusion.